# Css for a link not rendering

Tags: html, css

I have this link created in PHP:

```
echo '<p style="font-family: arial;">Solution name: <a class="expand_suggested_solution" href="#" data-suggestion_id="'.$suggested_solution_id.'"  data-problem_id="'.$problem_id.'">'.$solution_name.'</a></p>';
```

And I have this css for it:

```
a.expand_suggested_solution
{
    color: blue;
}
```

But I also tried a bunch of different things like

```
.expand_suggested_solution

{
    color: blue;
}

.expand_suggested_solution .a
{
    color: blue;
}
```

But none of those worked :) Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Its probably simple, but I just suck at css sometimes :)

Here it isn't working for some reason: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=223 in the "Existing Group Plans" link

Comment: The first is correct.  Could you try placing !important at the end (e.g. `blue !important;`) and see if it changes it then?

Comment: Where is the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/E53p6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule:

```
.ui-widget-content a {
    color: #222222;
}
```

In the jQuery theme (`http://hotlink.jquery.com/jqueryui/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css`) is more specific, and hence the link will be `#222222`.

You can make your rule more specific by doing something like:

```
.problem_comment_text a.expand_suggested_solution { color: blue; }
```

For an explanation of CSS specificity, see [here](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/).

Answer (score 1):

```
.expand_suggested_solution {
  color: blue
}
```

should work, but to be more precise, you can write it as:

```
a.expand_suggested_solution {
   color:blue
}
```

The selector would read as "any a element with a class of expand_suggested_solution".

If this is not working, it'll be some other problem.  Since you've written PHP here, i would double check to see your link is rendering out correctly to the browser by viewing the source on the executed page.

Comment: Definitely check your printed source. It has happened to all of us that the php prints a closing quote and just messes with your entire tag...

Comment: @Tomas here is where the problem is happening: view-source:http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=223 - looks like the link is ok...not sure what can be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What text do you actually wish to be blue? The link text or the "Solution name:" text?
If it's the latter, then you need to apply the css to the `<p>` tag.

Is the link not actually being echo'd to the page or just that it's not blue?
Sometimes swapping the quotes can be easier because you don't have to concatenate the variables ('.') you can just put them in.

```
echo "<p style='font-family: arial;'>Solution name:
        <a class='expand_suggested_solution' href='#'
           data-suggestion_id='$suggested_solution_id'
           data-problem_id='$problem_id'>$solution_name'
        </a>
      </p>";
```

Check the rest of your css for anything that overrides this css rule, eg `a {colour: #fff}` will override this if written after this rule.

You could always try putting an `!important` into your declaration to make sure nothing overrides it. eg `color: blue!important;`

Make sure you have a legitimate Doctype declaration too.

Answer (score 0):

As @wsanville rightfully pointed out, a selector already defined in jquery.ui.theme.css:

```
.ui-widget-content a {
  color: #222222;
}
```

is more specific than the first selector you tried:

```
.expand_suggested_solution {
  color: blue;
}
```

**Furthermore, your 2nd CSS selector syntax is incorrect:**

```
.expand_suggested_solution .a {
  color: blue;
}
```

Instead you meant:

```
a.expand_suggested_solution {
  color: blue;
}
```

*However, it's still not as specific as the one in jquery.ui.theme.css.*

You could try:

```
.ui-widget-content a.expand_suggested_solution {
  color: blue;
}
```

Or as @Daryl suggested:

```
a.expand_suggested_solution {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

because the [`!important`](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) declaration will trump any other selector.  However, I recommend using it sparingly!